# how to create a dApp to interact with a user using stable coins

Tags: solidity, dapps, stablecoins

I use my holidays to learn solidity. Since I've programming background is solidity not my biggest challenge. Remix online IDE and JavaScript VM are great tools to start with. I've created a smart contract where I can deposit and withdraw ether. But now I would like the dApp to interact with user based on a stable currency like tether. How is it possible. How can I prevent users to deposit or withdraw ether or other tokens and just allow to deposit and withdraw tether?

Comment: See [create-eth-app](https://github.com/paulrberg/create-eth-app), [solidity-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) and [scaffold-eth](https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth#-scaffold-eth).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent users to deposit or withdraw ether or other tokens?

You cannot prevent a user from sending ether to a smart contract.  Ether can be forcibly sent to a smart contract address.  (Read more about that here [Can i disable direct transactions to smart contract address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79234/can-i-disable-direct-transactions-to-smart-contract-address))  Once the contract is deployed, and even before the contract is deployed since it is possible to calculate a smart contracts address, anyone can send ether to the contract.

> and just allow to deposit and withdraw tether?

You can interact with tether or any ERC20 based token in a smart contract using the ERC20 contract interface.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;


interface ERC20 {
function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);

function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
function name() external view returns (string memory);
function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
} 

contract ERC20Interaction {
    ERC20 ercToken;

    constructor(address tokenAddress) {
        require(tokenAddress != address(0));
        ercToken = ERC20(tokenAddress);
    }

    function getSenderBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        uint senderBalance = ercToken.balanceOf(msg.sender);
        return senderBalance;
    }
    
    function interactWithToken() external {
        //interact with the token here
    }
}
```

**Note: This is just an example and is not considered to be audited, optimized or secure code.**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. So, when I've a stable coin address used onchain, I can't use only this address for deposits and withdrawals? like

```
function Deposit() public payable {
      require(tokenAddress ==0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f);
 }
  
function Withdraw(uint _amount) public payable  {

}
```

By the way, I dont want to create my own token, just to use stable coins in my dApp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).